# Bedeutung von "locker"

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet "locker" in den folgenden Beispielen:

> Das schaffe ich **locker** bis morgen.
>
> Mit dieser App lernen sie **locker** 50 Vokabeln pro Tag.

Das zweite Beispiel kann falsch sein, denn ich habe es aus der Erinnerung heraus geschrieben, und in Wahrheit kann es anders ausgesehen haben.

Ich vermute, es handelt sich um eine Schätzung, aber kein Wörterbuch sagt etwas dazu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"**Locker**" bedeutet hier "**leicht**". (Beide Beispiele sind korrekt.)

Der Zusammenhang zwischen "locker" und "leicht" rührt von der Redewendung "**locker und leicht**" her, einem klassischen Stabreim (Aliteration).

Andere Möglichkeiten der Bedeutung sind

- einfach
- problemlos